# Application to do image normalization on an image, with Least square adjustments

Tags: windows, gratis, image-processing

I want an application to do image normalization on an image, with:

- Least square adjustments
- Intensity hue saturation
- Pseudo invariant

Requirements:

- Free
- Runs on Windows

Comment: It seems that http://photo.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul anything that deals with applying least square adjustments on images .

Comment: For the MATLAB part, you should ask on http://stackoverflow.com Here we only recommend software, we don't talk about code.

Comment: I reformatted your question so that it does not get closed. Please check.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul thank you so much .. you know I asked the same question there .. they told me to post this here :(

Answer (score 1):

You can try [XnViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp).

1. Free and multiplatform
2. Can perform batch processing
3. Can adjust hue, contrast, saturation, color, size
4. Has two normalize functions
5. Edit with preview

[image]

Comment: I am working on relative normalization technique .